# quick launch items missing

Tags: publishing-site, navigation, quick-launch, custom-masterpage

For some reason the Quick Launch Items has gone missing from my custom masterpage and I am not sure hwo to get them back...

The code for my Quick Launch:

```
<Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager
                id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
                runat="server"
                QuickLaunchControlId="QuickLaunchMenu"
                ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
                EnableViewState="false"
                CssClass="ms-quicklaunch-navmgr">
                <div>
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
                        <Template_Controls>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
        </Template_Controls>
                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <SharePoint:AspMenu id="QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" ItemWrap="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" StaticSubMenuIndent="1" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-die">
                                <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                                    <asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-navheader" />
                                    <asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-navitem" />
                                </LevelMenuItemStyles>
                                <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                                    <asp:submenustyle CssClass="ms-navSubMenu1" />
                                    <asp:submenustyle CssClass="ms-navSubMenu2" />
                                </LevelSubMenuStyles>
                                <LevelSelectedStyles>
                                    <asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-selectednavheader" />
                                    <asp:menuitemstyle CssClass="ms-selectednav" />
                                </LevelSelectedStyles>
                            </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="SiteMapDataSource1" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
                </div>
                </Sharepoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

There is simply no items on the list. And I can't get them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Site Settings . Under Web Designer Galleries click master pages and page layouts. Look for your master pages version history. Then reload to the which version you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Site Settings for any settings related to Navigation before changing anything else. Code presented seems proper. Do you see the "Recycle Bin" and "View All Site Content"? (if yes, it can be most likely due to settings rather than the master page)

- If you use Publishing Site - check Navigation and make sure that
  under Current Navigation you have anything either Checked
  (Pages/Subsites) or add manually links.
- If you use Collaboration Site, make sure that Quick Launch hasn't been disabled (un-checked) in The "Tree View".